# Looking For 1/4" stereo -> dual L or R mono

Tags: hardware, cable, connector, y-cable

I'm looking for a cable that splits a **single** stereo 1/4" to **two separate** mono outputs (also 1/4"), **one left** and **the other right**. Do you know of one? The only thing I can find online mixes the stereo signal down into mono, *then* doubles it. The connections should either be (1) ALL male, if the whole cable is long (~2ft or longer) **or** (2) the stereo is male and the two outputs are female (then I can extend each using separate cables, but more of a hassle).

Thanks!

Comment: why not make one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general those will be called insert cables.  They have one stereo 1/4" plug on one end and two mono 1/4" plugs on the other.

Comment: They're also called Y cables.